# Trim Time from cell then calculate it

Tags: excel

I have a single cell with multiple time values separated by Enter(each time value in each line).

```
09:30
09:32
09:34
21:00
```

I want to subtract the first time value from the last time value. Is there any way to achieve a result?

P.S. I have tried extracting the first and last line using

```
=RIGHT(A1,FIND(CHAR(10),A1))
```

and

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(CHAR(10),A1))
```

Then tried subtracting one from another, but excel results #VALUE! after the subtraction. 
I tried Evaluating the formula and noticed that the time value does not converts to decimal for the calculation (which it should) and thus results nothing.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say in B1:

```
=RIGHT(A1,FIND(CHAR(10),A1)-1)
```

and in C1:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(CHAR(10),A1)-1)
```

then:

```
=TIMEVALUE(B1)-TIMEVALUE(C1)
```

should work.

Without the `-1`s you would be preventing conversion because of the line break characters.

You might combine all formulae into one:

```
=TEXT(TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(A1,FIND(CHAR(10),A1)-1))-TIMEVALUE(LEFT(A1,FIND(CHAR(10),A1)-1)),"hh:mm")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works like a charm. Although 1 more small problem is there. I have an extra blank line at the end of the cell A1. Due to which the result is still glitchy. Is there any way to handle that?

Comment: You made my day. Thanks a ton.